# Why resource-mapping don't work without annotation driven support enambled in this simple project?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations

I am quite news in Spring MVC world and I have an answer for you.

I have created a new Spring MVC Project by the related template project in STS\Eclipse.

Ok, it create for me a simple preconfigured Spring MVC Project.

This project is configured to be **annotation-driven** by the use of the following tag within **servlet-context.xml** file:

```
<annotation-driven />
```

This tag is an helper tag that provides additional services such as Message conversion, JSR 303 validation, etcetc and this is not strictly necessary so a simple controller work (I can just annotate the class as @Controller and specify the package to scan by the component-scan tag)

Ok...this is clear for me...but in the example created by STS\Eclipse I noticed that to work properly if I delete the **annotation-driven tag** from my servlet-context.xml file I have also to delete the following tag from the same configuration file:

```
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

If I delet the annotation-driven tag but I don't delete the previus resource mapping tag, when I start my application this don't run this don't run and go into error sayng me: HTTP Status 404 - and in the stack trace I have:

```
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/resources/**] onto handler 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0'
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'appServlet': initialization completed in 1104 ms
dic 03, 2012 12:57:16 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /home/andrea/SpringSource/vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.7.2.RELEASE/base-instance/webapps/ROOT
dic 03, 2012 12:57:16 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /home/andrea/SpringSource/vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.7.2.RELEASE/base-instance/webapps/manager
dic 03, 2012 12:57:16 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
dic 03, 2012 12:57:16 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 3144 ms
WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/maventestwebapp/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'
```

But if I delete also the previus resource-mapping tag the project run well...so it means that this must be the problem...seems like that without the annotation-driven support enambled the resource-mapping can not work...

Why? What is the problem? and what is the exact behavior of the previus resource-mapping tag?

Thank you so much

Andrea

---

This is the code of my **servlet-context.xml** configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<!--  <annotation-driven /> -->

<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.maventestwebapp" />

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" /> 

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

After going through your log file, the resources are loaded without any errors, but a warning is shown for the controller, "WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/maventestwebapp/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'". Which is the cause of 404 error I think.

As per spring specification, there is no relationship or dependency between,  <mvc:annotation-driven/> and  <mvc:resources />.

Also, I've tested a sample application without <mvc:annotation-driven/> by keeping <mvc:resources /> and it is working good. Post your servlet-config file for further investigation.

Comment: mmm this is very strange :-( how is it that I do not work if I disable only the annotation driven support?
I have post another post with the code of my dispatcherservlet configuration